# How do I create an exception for a link my "active" scroll menu in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, menu, href

I've got this code that goes through all my internal `href`s but I can't see to be able to figure out how to create an exception for one of the links that links to the div `#section1`. I need some kind of `if` statement surrounding the `section.addClass("active");` line but I don't know which conditions to use to achieve this. Can you help?

Code: http://jsfiddle.net/vD3vP/

```
    if (scrolledTo > target - threshold && scrolledTo < target + threshold) {

        //remove all selected elements
        sections.removeClass("active");

        //add current selected element.
        section.addClass("active");
    }
```

Comment: Your fiddle is just JS, no HTML to demonstrate the issue with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
$('a[href^="#"]:not(#exception)').click(function (event) {
    //do stuff
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/vD3vP/1/

**EDIT:** You can determine whether or not it is the exception like this:

```
//Smooth scroll when user click link that starts with #
$('a[href^="#"]').click(function (event) {

    if (!$(this).is('#exception')) {
        alert('Hi');
    }

    //prevent the browser from jumping down to section.
    event.preventDefault();

});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMuir/vD3vP/2/

Comment: Thank you, but if i add an exception like that then my section1 div wont removeClass("active") when i scroll up past the section2 div since the section1 div is never added to the sections! I need some kind of if statement so it just skips addClass(""active) on the section1 div!

Comment: got it working with:

   if (!section.is('#nav_section1')) {
    section.addClass("active");
   }

Answer (score 1):

Unless I misunderstood your question, you might add

```
$('a[href^="#section1"]').removeClass("active");
```

after section.addClass("active"); in the for loop inside checkSectionSelected().

You can do even better if you don't update the DOM tree unnecessarily using:

```
section.not('[href^="#section1"]').addClass("active");
```

Test here: http://jsfiddle.net/bcH3S/2/

Andrei